# Python: Yet Another AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror

I tried reading through some of the other questions but I still can't get it to work.

Basically I'm using a quick and dirty function called time_string() to return the date and time in a string formatted the way I want.  If I run time_string directly, it works fine.  If I call it from another function I get an AttributeError.

**time_string**

```
import time
def time_string(): #Never mind the unreadable formatting
    return str(time.localtime().tm_hour)+':'+str(time.localtime().tm_min)+':'+str(time.localtime().tm_sec)+\
           ' '+str(time.localtime().tm_year)+'/'+str(time.localtime().tm_mon)+'/'+str(time.localtime().tm_mday)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print time_string()
```

**Running time_string directly**

> 13:46:13 2012/7/19

**Other function**

```
from misc.time_string import time_string
def main():
    print time_string()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Running other function**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "#Filepath#",
>   line 10, in 
>       main()   File "#Filepath#",
>   line 7, in main
>       print time_string()   File "#Filepath#",
>   line 9, in time_string
>       ' '+str(time.localtime().tm_year)+'/'+str(time.localtime().tm_mon)+'/'+str(time.localtime().tm_mday)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'localtime'

I'm assuming its some issue with time not getting imported or something but it's boggling my mind

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you named one of your modules ``time.py`` b/c i think it's shadowing the stdlib time module.

Comment: I've tried renaming the module and function name to various things, including not using the same name, but to no avail

Comment: Y U NO [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)?

Comment: I copied and pasted these two scripts, and they worked fine in a vacuum. the only change I made was "from misc.time_string..." became "from misc import time_string"

Comment: in your ``time_string.py`` and after ``import time`` put this line: ``print repr(test)`` and tell us what you see, if you are really importing the stdlib time you should get: ``<module 'time' (built-in)>`` if not you will get something lile: ``<module 'time' from '<some_path>'>``

Comment: @mfrankli I tried that it didn't change anything

Comment: @mouad I got <module 'time' (built-in)> it must be importing correctly in time_string since it works when run on its own

Comment: you also need to remove the `time.pyc` file if it exists

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger You sir are a gentleman and a scholar! I guess at some point I had named something time in the folder.  All good now!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you have or at one time had a `time.py` file in the directory where you run the script, causing the wrong `time` module to be imported.

Even if you remove the `time.py` file, there still is a compiled `time.pyc` file that gets imported.